# using spring boot data redis template get a null pointer error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class RedisConfig extends CachingConfigurerSupport{

    @Bean(name = "template")
    public RedisTemplate<String, Object> template(RedisConnectionFactory factory) {
        RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(factory);
        Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<Object> jacksonSeial = new Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<>(Object.class);
        ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
        om.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.ALL, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
        om.enableDefaultTyping(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL);
        jacksonSeial.setObjectMapper(om);
        StringRedisSerializer stringSerial = new StringRedisSerializer();
        template.setKeySerializer(stringSerial);
        template.setValueSerializer(jacksonSeial);
        template.setHashKeySerializer(stringSerial);
        template.setHashValueSerializer(jacksonSeial);
        template.afterPropertiesSet();
        return template;
    }

}
```

use:

```
@Autowired
    private RedisTemplate<String, Object> template;
```

and this

```
  ValueOperations<String, Object> operations = template.opsForValue();
```

always get a error, [warn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfNTM.png)
stack trace is:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at cn.com.agree.afa.jcomponent.CacheOperationImpl.<init>(CacheOperationImpl.java:15) ~[afa-interface-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at tc.bank.base.B_MemaryHandle.getCache(B_MemaryHandle.java:36) ~[afa-component-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at tc.bank.base.B_MemaryHandle.B_PutGlobalCache(B_MemaryHandle.java:64) ~[afa-component-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at tc.bank.base.B_LoadData.B_LoadErrorCodeConfig(B_LoadData.java:146) [afa-component-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at cn.com.agree.afa.trade.AimServer.BASE_startup.execute(BASE_startup.java:53) [main/:na]
    at cn.com.agree.trade.TradeManager.execute(TradeManager.java:43) [afa-interface-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at cn.com.agree.afa.App.run(App.java:71) [main/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:804) [spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:788) [spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:333) [spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1309) [spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1298) [spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at cn.com.agree.afa.App.main(App.java:40) [main/:na]
```

I just want to use spring boot date redis to do some CRUD operations like template<String, Object>.
please help me

Comment: Method invocation 'opsForValue' will produce 'NullPointerException'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Field injection *can't* happen until after the constructor is already finished. Make the template a constructor parameter instead (and avoid field injection generally).

Comment: I can barely understand you, to be frank this is the first time me using spring-related stuff,  could you please show me exactly how to correct this?

Comment: @Django47 Make the template a parameter on your class's constructor like you would do if you had no Spring in the first place. (And get in the habit of never using `@Autowired` on fields, because it leads to problems like this; just pass anything you need in the constructor.)

Comment: I've change my code to ```private ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(RedisConfig.class);
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate = (RedisTemplate<String, Object>) ctx.getBean("redisTemplate");
    private ValueOperations<String, Object> operations = redisTemplate.opsForValue();```
and got new error```No CacheResolver specified, and no bean of type CacheManager found. Register a CacheManager bean or remove the @EnableCaching annotation from your configuration.```

Comment: after removing @EnableCaching the programe finally runs without error!
but I still need to know how the code get the yml or properties metrics

Comment: fanally using @Value("${spring...}")worked for me...

Answer (score 0):

Adding to chrylis answer here.

Use lombok's `@RequiredArgsConstructor` on top of your `@Component` class. It will generate a constructor with the required fields. Redis template will be initialized and null error will go away.

Comment: Yes, Lombok could help here, but we don't have information about Lombok dependencies in the project.